# Toggle One Div at a Time / Click on Open Div and it will close

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to toggle divs such that only one div is only open at one time. I have looked at the other solutions provided, however the solutions provided are such that if I clicked on the open div again, it does not close. And I am looking for the currently opened div to close again when clicked. Any help given is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

JSFIDDLE:http://jsfiddle.net/ZmDs2/78/

HTML

```
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>From</th>
                <th>Utensil</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr class="list">
                <td class="title">Cupcakes</td>
                <td class="from">Molly's Cupcakes</td>
                <td>Chopsticks</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="description">
                <td>hello </td>
            </tr>


            <tr class="list">
                <td class="title">Pizza</td>
                <td>Roberta's</td>
                <td>Knife</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="description">
                <td>bye </td>
            </tr>


            <tr class="list">
                <td>Pasta</td>
                <td>Basta Pasta</td>
                <td>Spoon</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="list">
                <td>Chicken & Waffles</td>
                <td>cell is row 3, column 1</td>
                <td>Spoon</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

CSS

```
.description{
    display:none;
}
```

JS:

```
    $('.title').on('click', function() {
      var $this = $(this),
          $next = $this.next();

      // Check if another profile is open and close it
      var $last = $('.description:visible', $this.parents('table'));

      if ($last.length) {
        $last.slideUp('fast');
      }

      // Show the new profile content only if we are opening a new profile
      if ($last.parents('.list').index() !== $this.parent().index()) {
        $next.slideDown('fast');
      }
    });
```

Comment: The code in your jsfiddle doesn't match the code you posted. At all.

Comment: @AndreaJessup sorry about that. updated it.

Comment: Can you clarify the instructions, then? This code is a table, with no <div> - what exactly do you need to have open/close on click? Also, the code in the JSFiddle doesn't "work" (no change on click). Is this expected?

Comment: @AndreaJessup When user clicks on .title, it should show .description. Is it possible to make that happen in a table? Yes, the current code in the jsFiddle does not work. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads-up to avoid "reinventing the wheel" unless necessary. The bootstrap library has a Collapse element which does what you require.

[Check it out](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) and see if it fits the bill.

Comment: I managed to make it work with the collapse element. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Created a collapse element from the Twitter Bootstrap library.

```
<table class="table table-condensed" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>From</th>
                            <th>Utensil</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="list">
                            <td data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#cupcakes" class="accordion-toggle">Cupcakes</td>
                            <td class="from">Molly's Cupcakes</td>
                            <td>Chopsticks</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="10" class="hiddenRow"><div class="accordion-body collapse" id="cupcakes">hello</div></td>
                        </tr>


                        <tr class="list">
                            <td data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#pizza" class="accordion-toggle">Pizza</td>
                            <td class="from">Roberta's</td>
                            <td>Knife</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="10" class="hiddenRow"><div class="accordion-body collapse" id="pizza">bye</div></td>
                        </tr>


                        <tr class="list">
                            <td data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#pasta" class="accordion-toggle">Pasta</td>
                            <td>Basta Pasta</td>
                            <td>Spoon</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="10" class="hiddenRow"><div class="accordion-body collapse" id="pasta">hi</div></tr>
                        </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```